# How to convert "2021-10-10 13:06:26.666855" Timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: python, python-2.x

Want to convert date and time into milliseconds, Given format is `2021-10-10 13:06:26.666855` and output format should be like this `1635157405000`

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.7 you can do this as follows, using the format dictated by the datetime library. Conversion from string to the correct format can be done with Xnero's answer.

```
import time
from datetime import *

d = datetime(2021, 10, 10, 6, 26.666855)

unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())

print(unixtime * 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating a `date` object, stripping the time and multiplying it by 1000:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime('2021-10-10 13:06:26.666855',
                           '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
milliseconds = date.timestamp() * 1000
```

Comment: not working for the python 2X version.
    millisec = date.timestamp() * 1000
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Comment: @KuldeepYadav In your question, you say you use Python 3.

Comment: Check out my answer, it works in python 2.7 for me.

Comment: @Anteino Your answer does not do what the question asked. It's asking to convert the time stamp to milliseconds, not convert passed time into milliseconds.

Comment: A timestamp is effectively the same as passed time. But I get your point and my answer was indeed not quite answering the question so I changed it.